# Solve system of 2 equations and 2 unknowns results in "cannot be solved'

Tags: equation-solving

I have this set of two equations with two unknowns. Here is my code.

Solve[2^(n + 1) x + (2^n - 1) == 7423 && (2 x + 1) 3^n - 1 == 
   190268, {n, x}, Integers]

Here is my result message.
Solve: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.

I know this solves for:
n=8 and x=14.

My question is: What is it about this equation that Mathematica is having difficulty solving. Is there another way I can approach this question to solve for n and x?

Thanks.

Comment: Simple syntax mistake. `Solve[{2^(n + 1) x + (2^n - 1) == 7423 && (2 x + 1) 3^n - 1 == 190268}, {n, x}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gives solution if you relax it to `Reals`, Not sure why, but solutions are integers.

```
eq1=2^(n+1) x+(2^n-1)==7423;
eq2=(2 x+1) 3^n-1==190268;
Solve[{eq1,eq2},{n,x},Reals]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: FindInstance behaves exactly the same way

Comment: Include constraint that `n>0`; `Solve[{eq1, eq2, n > 0}, {n, x}]`

Comment: Thanks... So when I have this type of issue, is it a matter of just cycling through the constraints/domains, such as Reals, Integers and the like to see if I get one that seems to work?

Comment: @BTBlueSkies In theory it should have worked with `Integers` domain. But not knowing why it did not work, one can only try something else and hope it works.  This time it worked with `Reals`. We users can only try something and see what happens.